# Overwrite .INI file using batch file with parameter containing equal sign

Tags: batch-file, parameters, ini

Want to overwrite a text or ini file using a batch file with a parameter batch file I'm using for this should be:

```
@echo %1>text.ini
```

and after running this cmd:

```
c:\..\text.bat Hello=60
```

I only get Hello in my ini file the =60 disappeared.

I also remarked, when i do:

```
@echo %1%2>text.ini
```

I get Hello60 in my ini file

but I need the Hello=60, can anyone help me for this?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
c:\..\text.bat "Hello=60"
```

---

```
@>text.ini echo %~1
```

Comment: A cryptic answer for a cryptic question. The answer could really use some explanatory text. But +1 anyway for a working solution.